# How to prevent a centered aligned flex item from going up as its height increases?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, dropdown

I'm trying to build a dropdown menu, but its div (which is position static) keeps going up as I add new items to the menu.

It's the `align-items:center` rule that keeps repositioning the item so it's properly vertically aligned.

If I discard this rule, it'll break the navbar, the other items won't be centered as I intended.

If I use the `display` property, as the code bellow shows, the button starts where I want but whenever I click on it, it goes out of its place.

```js
const dropdown = () => {
    let display = document.getElementById("menu").style.display;
    
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = (display === "none") ? "block":"none";
    //toggling "visibility" takes the div out of its place
 }
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:160px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;    
}

.dropdownContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
}

#drop {
  display:none;
  /* visibility:hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div>Irrelevant elements to this question</div>
    <div class="dropdownContainer">
        <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropdownBtn">Ronaldinho</button> 
        <div id="menu">
            <!-- the more items added here, the more up the page the whole container goes -->
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Two</div>
            <div>Three</div>
            <div>Four</div>
            <div>Five</div>
            <div>Six</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If I change the JS code so it toggles the `visibility` property instead, the button already starts out of its intended position but it also doesn't change place when its clicked on.

How can I keep the button centered as it is and make the menu drop down without changing the button's place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that's what you want to achieve:

I positioned your menu underneath the button with position absolute. so the button won't change its position.

```js
const dropdown = () => {
    let display = document.getElementById("menu").style.display;
    
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = (display === "none") ? "block":"none";
    //toggling "visibility" takes the div out of its place
 }
```

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdownContainer {
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#drop {
  display: none;
  /* visibility:hidden;*/
}
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div>Irrelevant elements to this question</div>
    <div class="dropdownContainer">
        <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropdownBtn">Ronaldinho</button> 
        <div id="menu">
            <!-- the more items added here, the more up the page the whole container goes -->
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Two</div>
            <div>Three</div>
            <div>Four</div>
            <div>Five</div>
            <div>Six</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dropdown = () => {
    let display = document.getElementById("menu").style.display;
    
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = (display === "none") ? "block":"none";
    //toggling "visibility" takes the div out of its place
 }
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:160px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;    
}

.dropdownContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
}

#drop {
  display:none;
  /* visibility:hidden;*/
}
#menu{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 60px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div>Irrelevant elements to this question</div>
    <div class="dropdownContainer">
        <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropdownBtn">Ronaldinho</button> 
        <div id="menu">
            <!-- the more items added here, the more up the page the whole container goes -->
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Two</div>
            <div>Three</div>
            <div>Four</div>
            <div>Five</div>
            <div>Six</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```